# Combining Multiple Rows into one row with separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am attempting to write a query in which one of the tables I am joining could contain multiple rows for each unique id. I would like to combine these rows in my results so that each unique id has only one row.

Please see the simplified example below:

`Tender` table:

```
ID     | TenderType    |  TenderAmount 
----------------------------------------
4567   | Cash          |  40.00
4568   | Cash          |  22.00
4568   | Visa          |  86.00
4568   | Gift Card     |  10.00
4570   | Cash          |  66.00
4570   | MC            |  30.00
```

Desired results:

```
ID   | TenderType1 | TenderType2 | TenderType3 | TenderAmount1 | TenderAmount2 | TenderAmount3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4567 | Cash        |             |             | 40.00         |               |               |
4568 | Cash        | Visa        | Gift Card   | 22.00         | 86.00         | 10.00         |
4570 | Cash        | MC          |             | 66.00         | 30.00         |               |
```

I am using SQL Server 2005. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: I just love this phrase:  "one of the tables I am joining could contain multiple rows for each unique id".  The ids are not *unique* if they are repeated.  (I do know what you mean, though.)

Comment: Ha! I see how that could be misread. In the original table the value would not be unique, but in my query it would (hopefully) be.

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'pivot'. You should look up how to do pivot tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CashCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
           TenderType,
           TenderAmount
    FROM   Tender
    WHERE  TenderType = 'Cash'
),GiftCardCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
           TenderType,
           TenderAmount
    FROM   Tender
    WHERE  TenderType = 'Gift Card'
),CreditCardCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, 
           TenderType,
           TenderAmount
    FROM   Tender
    WHERE  TenderType IN ('Visa','MC')
)

SELECT COALESCE(C.ID,G.ID,V.ID) AS ID,
       C.TenderType AS TenderType1,
       V.TenderType AS TenderType2,
       G.TenderType AS TenderType3,
       C.TenderAmount AS TenderAmount1,
       V.TenderAmount AS TenderAmount2,
       G.TenderAmount AS TenderAmount3
FROM   CashCTE C
       FULL OUTER JOIN GiftCardCTE G
           ON C.ID = G.ID
       FULL OUTER JOIN CreditCardCTE V
           ON C.ID = V.ID
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25de0/5)**

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Pivot to accomplish this.  Description and examples in this link:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx